# Hide virtual products on backend listing

Tags: magento2, product, backend, listing

I have a lot of configurable product in my backend listing, I'd like to know how can I hide all my virtual product ? (I want to show only configurable products on my backend).

Can I do this from the backoffice or should I hide them programmaticaly ? And how ?

Comment: Did you try filter listing?

Comment: I don't want to simply add a filter, because I don't want the user to have control on this (he won't be able to see them through backend listing).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have **SR_MagentoCommunity** module. Now added folowing file in your module that will avoid showing **virtual** type product in admin grid.

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider">
        <plugin name="sr_product_list" type="SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Plugin/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/ProductDataProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product;

class ProductDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider $subject
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterGetCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider $subject,
        $collection
    ) {
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('type_id', ['nin' => 'virtual']);
        return $collection;
    }
}
```